# Excessive memory usage when creating one SQL database from another

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am trying to iterate through one SQLite database (I'll call it Database A), create some new variables from the data within it, and then write this new data to a new SQLite database (Database B).

Database A is made up of tables that are comprised of tweets about certain terms for a certain month (each tweet and its metadata is a row, and every day of the month is included). Each table is roughly 0.5 GB in size.

So, I am iterating through these tables, creating a variable, and then writing/committing this new data to Database B.

The problem is that after iterating through a few tables the working memory (I have 16 GB of RAM) on the server I am using becomes completely used up (using the `free -m` command in BASH, I can see that about half the RAM is being used by 'buff/cache'). This does not generate any errors that I can see in my output file (which usually shows Python error messages), but the script stops running.

I think this a result of the temporary files created by SQLite (https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html), which continue growing as the for loop continues. So, I have tried to iterate through the rows in the table day by day, and commit the new data to Database B after every day, so that the Rollback Journal (see above link) - one of these temporary SQL files - is deleted (thereby freeing memory). However, even after making these changes, I run into the same problem (the script stopping).

I am not sure how much code will help here, but here's a basic outline of what I am doing:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas

#this defines the SQL query; [long list of columns] is just comma separated column names: id, date, time, etc.
sql_query = ("SELECT DISTINCT [long list of columns] "
            "FROM term "
            "WHERE date = 'day';")

### HERE I GET ALL TABLES IN DATABASE A ###

#go through all the tables in Database A
for t in tables:

   term = t

   ### HERE I GET THE DAYS IN THE CURRENT TABLE ###

   #go through each day in the current table in Database A
   for day in days:

      #open the databases
      connection = sqlite3.connect("../SQL_database/Database_A.db3")
      lite_cursor = connection.cursor()
      connection_new = sqlite3.connect("../SQL_database/Database_B.db3")
      lite_cursor_new = connection_new.cursor()

      #change SQL query to match current day and term
      sql_query = sql_query.replace('day', day)

      #extract the data from the database and put it in the new database
      for chunk in pandas.read_sql_query(sql_query, connection, chunksize = 10000):

         ### HERE I PROCESS THE DATA ###

         #add the current data set to Database B
         new_table = term
         chunk.to_sql(new_table, connection_new, if_exists='append', index=True)

         #redefine SQL query; [long list of columns] is just comma separated column names: id, date, time, etc.
         sql_query = ("SELECT DISTINCT [long list of columns] "
                     "FROM term "
                     "WHERE date = 'day';")

         #commit the changes
         connection_new.commit()

         #close the databases
         connection.close()
         connection_new.close()
```

Of course, what I want is for the script to run without pausing/crashing! Is there any way to clear the SQLite memory cache so that RAM doesn't get eaten up as the for loop continues? I thought that commit() would release some memory, but apparently it is not releasing enough.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would be more confident in SQLite to save memory than in pandas. I have many times successfully processed tables greater than my available memory, but of course I had no tried to load everything in memory at the same time (what pandas does).

Comment: Hi, thanks for engaging. I had thought the same thing, which is why I queried by day in the table using `pandas.read_sql_query()`, but perhaps even this still reads the entire table (which is comprised of all the days in the month). Still, the strange thing is that the script fails after iterating through a few tables (not after the first), which suggests to me that its not reading the tables with pandas that is the problem, but instead some cache system that continues to grow in size. Perhaps I am missing something, though!

Comment: I see that you do not close your cursors. They have separate resource allocations. Maybe the connection does not keep track of its cursors and so cannot clean them up. So try closing them as well. See if that makes any difference.

Comment: I have just had a second look at your code. Something worries me: you repeatedly close and re-open the database connections. AFAIK, it it useless and could even be harmful if the close returns before the database has completely  freed everything, because it could have problems on next open. It is probably what happens, because I cannot imagine what in your code could eat so much memory.

Comment: @Dunes, I am currently trying this solution. It takes about 4 - 5 hours to fill up the 16 GB RAM, so I will let you know in the morning. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Dunes, I tried adding `lite_cursor.close` and `lite_cursor_new.close()` to the above code, but again ran into the same problem. This time I monitored the memory usage with the `free-m` command in BASH - about half the RAM was used by 'buff/cache' at the point of all memory being used.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, I',m re-checking your solution now. My original script closed the database connections at the end, but then I changed this after reading the SQL documentation (https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html), which I thought suggested that cached files are only deleted after closing the database connection (so I thought this might solve the problem). As I run the script again using your method, I see that the memory usage jumps after each day is complete (each SQL query is for a particular day in the month - see code above). The script also crashed when querying the whole month / table.

Comment: Could it be an option to get rid of pandas and to directly use sql to transfer the data? Said differently what is the content of `sql_query`?

Comment: @SergeBallesta thanks again for continuing to think about this! Perhaps it would? I've updated the question to include the definition of `sql_query`. Also, I tried your solution of only opening / closing the database connections once (at the start and end of the script); I still had the same memory problems, with half of the used memory in buff/cache.

Comment: I suspect `SELECT DISTINCT` may not help... SQLite will (I suspect) need to track all matching records to determine which, if any, have duplicated fields. I'm guessing there isn't an index on the "_long list of columns_"?

Comment: buff/cache? Don't worry about that. It's effectively the same as free memory. The OS tries to use any free memory to cache the filesystem to increase performance. That is, reading from a memory cache is faster than reading from disk. If any process ever needs more memory than is in "free" then the memory from the buff/cache is freed to make way for the process. Having a lot of memory used by buff/cache just means you are doing a lot of I/O on many or large files -- which you are.

Comment: @Dunes, thanks for that explanation. Yeah, I definitely wasn't aware of how that all worked. So, very helpful (and hopefully helpful to some other newbies out there as well)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to do that directly at the sqlite level.

Sqlite has the ability to attach an additional database to a current connection, which allows to easily copy tables between different databases. As you do not add a lot of processing, pandas is rather useless and `ATTACH DATABASE` should be enough:

```
import sqlite3

#this defines the SQL query; [long list of columns] is just comma separated column names: id, date, time, etc.
sql_query = ("SELECT DISTINCT [long list of columns] "
            "FROM term "
            "WHERE date = 'day';")

#open the databases
connection = sqlite3.connect("../SQL_database/Database_A.db3")
connection.execute("ATTACH DATABASE '../SQL_database/Database_B.db3' as db_B")

### HERE I GET ALL TABLES IN DATABASE A ###

#go through all the tables in Database A
for t in tables:

   term = t

   ### HERE I GET THE DAYS IN THE CURRENT TABLE ###

   #go through each day in the current table in Database A
   for day in days:

      #change SQL query to match current day and term
      # but don't change original query because we'll need it on next iteration
      sql_query2 = sql_query.replace('day', day) 
      sql_query2 = sql_query2.replace('term', term) 

      # print(sql_query2, end=' ')           # uncomment to make sure of what happens

      # copy table values
      try:
          connection.execute("INSERT INTO db_B.{} ".format(term) + sql_query2)
          # print('inserted')                    # uncomment for traces
      except sqlite3.OperationalError:  # table does not exists
          connection.rollback()
          connection.execute("CREATE TABLE db_B.{} AS ".format(term) + sql_query2)
          # print('created')                     # uncomment for traces

   connection.commit()

connection.close()
```

Here the only possibly resource consuming operation is the `SELECT DISTINCT` which requires to scan the whole table to only keep distinct rows for the given day, but the resources should be freed on each commit. It might take some time depending on the number and size of your tables, but it should not crash.

---

Late addition to this answer, but I have just realized that there was a number of request using `DISTINCT` keyword and `WHERE date =`. Database performances can be greatly increased by indexes. Here adding an index before extracting the informations will have a significant impact in time and memory:

```
...
for t in tables:

   term = t

   connection.execute("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS I{0} ON {0}(date)"
                      .format(term))

   ### HERE I GET THE DAYS IN THE CURRENT TABLE ###
...
```

Comment: Thanks again for all your help with this! I began monitoring the memory being used, and adding the index before extraction led to a substantial reduction in memory use.